# imdb dataset select movie count according to year with movies with only female cast

Tags: python, mysql, sql, count, average

[image]
report for each year the percentage of movies in that year with only female actors, and the total number of movies made that year. For example, one answer will be: 1990 31.81 13522 meaning that in 1990 there were 13,522 movies, and 31.81% had only female actors. You do not need to round your answer.

following code

```
select a.year, a.c*100.00/b.c as percentage, b.c as total_overall
from (select z.year, count(*) as c
      from movie z
      where not exists (select *
                        from person x,M_cast xy
                        where x.pid = xy.pid and xy.mid = z.mid and x.Gender!='Female')
      group by z.year) a,
     (select z.year, count(*) as c from movie z group by z.year) b
where a.year=b.year
order by a.year;
```

following code is not working

```
select z.year, count(*)
from movie z
where not exists (select *
                  from actor x, casts xy
                  where x.id = xy.pid and xy.mid = z.id and x.gender!='F')
group by z.year;
```

please tell me query for movies with only female how to select
following output im getting
[image]

guide me how to select movie with only female actors

[image]

how to write sql query for above statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select movie_year, count(*) no_movies, avg(has_male_actor = 0) ratio
from (
    select m.year movie_year, max(p.gender = 'Male') has_male_actor
    from movie m
    inner join m_cast mc on mc.mid = m.mid
    inner join person p on pid = mc.pid
    group by m.mid, m.year
) t
group by movie_year
```

The subquery produces one row per movie, with a flag that indicates if any male actor appears in the cast. Then, the outer query aggregates by year, and compute the counts and the ratio of movies having female actores only (expressed as a decimal number between `0` and `1`).

Comment: thanks for suggeston but i want to calculate percentage of film

Comment: @pratikpatil . . . Did you run the query?  This seems to do what you want.

Comment: it doesn't return any thing

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @gmb is correct as he doesn't know whether your data contain any noise or not and he wrote the query as per the schema you have mentioned above in the image. But when I encounter the same problem statement then I run it and find that the year column of movie table contain some `spaces and roman values` in front of it like:- 'I 1945' and after some modification, it runs successfully on your mentioned `'IMDB movies DB'` and returns the correct result.

Here is the modified query for the above problem statement:-

```
select  movie_year, count(*) no_movies, avg(has_male_actor = 0)*100 ratio
from (
    select CAST(SUBSTR(m.year,-4) AS UNSIGNED) movie_year, max(p.gender = 'Male') has_male_actor
    from movie m
    inner join m_cast mc on TRIM(mc.mid) = TRIM(m.mid)
    inner join person p on TRIM(p.pid) = TRIM(mc.pid)
    group by m.mid, m.year
) t
group by movie_year
```